# How can I submit changes to a Git repository without making a pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

A friend of mine is doing a project on Bitbucket and I downloaded one single script from his repository and did some changes.
Now he asked me if I could send him a pull request so he could review the changes and commit the new version.

I have a Bitbucket account, but I don't have much interest in forking and cloning his project just for a single change.

Are there other ways to send him a pull request, or more generally, to send him updates to single files without using pull requests at all?

Comment: He may be able to add you as a contributor to the project, so that you can `git push` directly to his repository.  You can also browse the source on the Bitbucket web page and hit `Edit`, although again you may need to be an owner/contributor of the project.

Comment: I'll give that a try

Comment: I don't understand why you set yourself this mental barrier of "not making a pull request". It would have take you the same time to fork/make the pr/delete the repo (after merge) than take the time to ask and wait for the answer... It's really easy, don't hesitate and do it!

Comment: His Repo doesn't contain scripts only but his entire home folder and most of the things he developed. From the point of efficiency I don't see a reason to fork ~1Gb just to alter a 1kb Script

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the popular [*merge workflow*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_merge_workflow), Git also supports a [*patch-driven workflow*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_patch_workflow).  With Git installed on your local machine, commit the changes normally.  Then send your friend a patch series with [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch):

```
git format-patch origin/master..
```

This generates one patch per commit between `origin/master` and `HEAD`.  (The refspec `origin/master..` can of course be changed; read the manual page.)

If you do not have Git installed, and for some reason do not wish to, you can send him a patch with plain `diff` (if you have the original version):

```
diff -u script.sh.orig script.sh
```

Either way, he can apply the patch(es) with [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply).

Of course, for a single file, you can also just email it to him, and he can drop it into his working directory, overwriting the original file.  Git will calculate the diff for him automatically.  This does not scale very well for larger changes though.

Comment: That's actually the way I'd like to avoid, but I fear that's the way it is

Comment: I edited to mention `format-patch`.  You didn't mention if you have Git installed on your local machine, so I overlooked it initially.  But yeah, without a remote repository for him to pull from, you're "stuck" emailing patches (which works very well, by the way, for many use-cases).

Answer (score 0):

If it were github, you could fork the project only at server, edit it through web interface and sumbit a pullrequest without running anything locally, and remove the fork after PR is accepted. Probably, at bitbucket it is also possible.